# How to get the natural indices in pandas?

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to get the unique values in a Data frame. I used `drop.duplicates()` but after that, i got the unique values but the indexing are not in natural order. Indexing was something like, 0,1,5,9,15, etc...I wanted a natural indexing like 0,1,2,3,4 etc after doing `drop.duplicated()`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just reassign the index after drop duplcated, ie:

```
 df.index = range(0,len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df= df.reset_index()
```

should do the trick! For more information on what this does, and its arguments you can read the documentation below.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html